# How do I design my switch case function in base class under this situation

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, switch-statement

Let's say we have a Person class

```
class Person{
   int id;
   Status* cur_status;
   ...
}
```

and we have class Status as follows:

```
class Status{
    int income;
    int tax;
    virtual void reform(int _case);
    ...
}

class Unemployed : public Status{
    void reform(int _case){
        switch (_case){
            case 1: tax /= 2;   //recession
            case 2: tax /= 3;   //depression
            case 3: tax = 0;
            ...
        }
    }
}

class Worker : public Status{
    void reform(int _case){
        switch (_case){
            case 1: tax /= 2;   //recession
            case 2: tax /= 3;   //depression
            case 3: tax = 100;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Given the person, his/her status could be changed dynamically,
so now I've encountered a problem:
Some of the reformation case are the SAME between 2 statuses, while the others are not.
Do I have to declare ALL OF 'EM in the derived class respectively ?
Actually, I want to extract the common case into Base class, but I don't know how.
Is there anyone could help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
class Unemployed : public Status{
    void reform(int _case){
        switch (_case){
          // Special case for this kind of Status
          case 1:
            tax /= 2;
            break;
          // Everything else is implemented by base class
          default:
            Status::reform(_case);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From OP' example, it is the case 3 which is specific to the class.

Comment: @Jarod42 The approach still applies. We leave details as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Does Status::reform(_case); mean that it's a static function ?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Thank u sir, so just call the parent function.
This answer is all I want